# Equivalence of quadratic forms over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider two quadratic forms:

$Q(x,y,z,w)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+bw^{2}$  and

$P(x,y,z,w)=x^{2}+y^{2}+czw$.

I am only interested in the case when are p and q congruent over $\mathbb{C}$ as I have done the case over $\mathbb{R}$.

This question was part of my linear algebra assignment and I was unable to find a theorem which could be used for $\mathbb{C}$ so I thought of posting it here.

Kindly tell me how to solve this question and which result you are using.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is quadratically closed (because it is algebraically closed). Therefore two quadratic forms are equivalent if and only if they have the same ranks.

Comment: equivalently, it's worth trying to prove Sylvester's Law of Inertia for a complex symmetric bilinear (not Hermitian) form.  If you look at the Diagonal matrix that you have congruence to, re: the diagonal entries, the number of zeros are determined by rank... and all other points on the diagonal are on the unit circle whose polar angle you may arbitrarily choose.